# t-sql query that takes up about 16% of the servertime

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

We have a query that runs for every user on our site before it's cached. The query takes up about 16% of all the questions accordingly to newrelic.

It's not a very good query and we should probably change the table design but we need a quick fix for us to have time to rewrite this function.

The query sometimes takes over 3 seconds to run.

Here is the query.

```
SELECT 
   q.QuickLinkID
   , q.QuickLinkUID
   , q.SchoolID
   , q.Url
   , q.Name
   , q.Target
   , q.OnlyTeachers
   , q.UserNumber 
FROM 
   Quicklinks AS q WITH (NOLOCK) 
LEFT JOIN 
   schoolParticipants AS sp WITH (NOLOCK) ON q.schoolID = sp.schoolID 
WHERE 
   (sp.userID = ? OR q.UserNumber = ?) 
   AND (q.schoolID = ? OR q.SchoolID NOT IN (SELECT qe.SchoolID 
                                             FROM Quicklinkexclude AS qe WITH (NOLOCK) 
                                             WHERE qe.userID = ?)) 
   AND ((sp.isTeacher > ? AND q.OnlyTeachers = ?) OR q.OnlyTeachers = ?) 
ORDER BY 
   q.Name
```

Comment: This isn't a great question... What kind of research have you done yourself?  Did you try SQL Profiler?  Looking at the query plan?  Usually table scans are bad, try and see where those are happening.

Comment: What's your question? It looks like you know what the problem is and now need to dedicate the time optimizing that query :)

Comment: Have you created relevant index based on your join and selection? Try alternative way for sub query if subquery return many rows.

Comment: Also please see [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) and [Bad habits to kick : Avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix.aspx).

Comment: You should probably look into adding indices, index fragmentation, and removing the not in to an in in some fashion

Comment: Sorry for the bad question.

Yes we have all the neccesary indexes and no table Scans are performed. SQL profiler and tuning advisor doesn't suggest any index Changes.

Comment: This is the "kitchen sink" - one plan to satisfy 100+ combinations of parameters. This will never end well. Please watch [this video](http://sqlsentry.tv/the-kitchen-sink-procedure/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your subquery to a join and apply indices on your ID columns:

```
SELECT q.QuickLinkID
     , q.QuickLinkUID
     , q.SchoolID
     , q.Url
     , q.Name
     , q.Target
     , q.OnlyTeachers
     , q.UserNumber 
FROM Quicklinks AS q WITH (NOLOCK) 
LEFT JOIN schoolParticipants AS sp WITH (NOLOCK) ON q.schoolID = sp.schoolID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN QuickLinkexclude AS qe ON q.SchoolID = qe.SchoolID
WHERE (sp.userID = ? OR q.UserNumber = ?)
    AND qe.SchoolID IS NULL
    AND qe.userID = ?
AND   ((sp.isTeacher > ? AND q.OnlyTeachers = ?) OR q.OnlyTeachers = ?)
```

The subquery is likely causing a table scan.  With a join, if you're using proper indices, it can be a seek, which is much faster in most cases.

Not tested, but this should work.